# Message: Failed to complete converge action

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, test-kitchen

```
PS C:\App\cookbooks\windows_settings> kitchen verify
---> Starting Kitchen (v1.4.2)
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/webagent-cookie.rb:458: warning: a
lready initialized constant HTTPClient::CookieManager
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/cookie.rb:8: warning: previous def
inition of CookieManager was here
---> Converging <default-windows-2012r2>...
      Preparing files for transfer
      Preparing dna.json
      Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 4.0.1...
      Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
      Preparing validation.pem
      Preparing client.rb
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #converge action: [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not pr
operly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. -
connect(2) for "ec2-54-213-41-35.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 5985 (http://ec2-54-213-41-35.us-west-2.compute.a
mazonaws.com:5985)]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

I am not able to do kitchen converge action, everytime I am facing the specified above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, the port 5985 is not opened on the test server. Can you please check the security group of the server, if the rule 'WinRM-HTTP' to connect 5985 is opened in inbound rules.
If the port is opened, you may tell the test kitchen to wait until the WinRM is ready, using the below parameters in kitchen.yml:

max_wait_until_ready: true
connection_timeout : 900

see here https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html#transport-settings